# How can I use subtitles with video in HTML5 (and Reveal.js)

Tags: html5-video, reveal.js

I have subtitles prepared in .ssa (SubStation Alpha) format and they work fine in VLC player. I would like to play this video from my local machine within reveal.js presentation with subtitles displayed. How?

I see this: https://github.com/spiegeleixxl/html5-ass-subtitles but it is dated and from the description, limited.

Am I limited to .vvt format as per here http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/track/basics/?

Would be good to know if there is an established workflow for this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

(2020-1-15)
I am also looking for a way to play `.ass` subtitle with `<video>`
Here are the only 2 options I found:

- https://github.com/Dador/JavascriptSubtitlesOctopus
- https://github.com/weizhenye/ASS